# @selector gives call to wrong method

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimer

I have a `ViewController` **A**, and in it's `viewDidLoad` I have the following code to call a method repeatedly (defined in **A**):

```
NSTimer* myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 15.0 target: self
                                                  selector: @selector(getAllNotificationDetails) userInfo: nil repeats: YES];
```

Now in another `ViewController` **B**, I have the same method. And in my `ViewController` A, I have imported **B**. Now the above piece of code gives call to the method in **B**, which is not what I want, I want the method in **A** to be called. I don't know why this is happens even when my target is `self`. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You may need to give a little more context.  Also have you confirmed that viewController "B" is getting the call in the debugger?

Comment: Did you command click the function name and it got you redirected to a different `UIViewController` or did you put a break point and method in A never gets called?

Comment: @Rikh: I did command+click.

Comment: @Sulthan: #import B.